# Why $\|a\| \|b\|\leq \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\|a\| \|b\|\leq \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2$.

I approached like this

$$\|a\|\|b\|\leq\begin{cases}\|a\|^2,\text{ if $\|b\|\leq\|a\|$}\\ \|b\|^2,\text{ if $\|a\|\leq\|b\|$}\\\end{cases}.$$ Hence $\|a\| \|b\|\leq \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2$. Is this correct? Is there any other way to show it?

Comment: Try to expand $0 \le (\|a\|-\|b\|)^2$.

Comment: There are other ways (as others have shown) but your way is correct as well.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is correct. Good proof.

Comment: The (better) inequality $\|a\| \|b\|\leq \frac 12 (\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2)$ is an application of the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean.

Comment: In fact, there's no need for norms in this theorem: $xy\le(x^2+y^2)/2$ works for arbitrary reals $x,\,y$, so it's not a linear algebra exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to notice that

$$\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2-\lVert a\rVert\lVert b\rVert=\underbrace{\left(\lVert a\rVert-\lVert b\rVert\right)^2}_{\geq0}+\underbrace{\lVert a\rVert\lVert b\rVert}_{\geq0}\geq0.$$

Your solution is correct as well though, well done.

Answer (score 2):

$$||a||^2+||b||^2-||a||||b||=\left(||a||-\frac{1}{2}||b||\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}||b||^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y \ge 0$ we have

$$ 0 \le (x-y)^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy,$$

thus

$$ xy \le 2xy \le x^2+y^2.$$